# Make JPanel takes full width of JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JPanel` to place inside a `JFrame`, I want them both to occupy the full width of the frame but I don't know how. Also I'm not a big fan of the `setBounds()` method so I was wondering if there is a way to just make the component take the full width and just specify the desired height after.

Here is my code:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel header = new JPanel();
        header.setBounds(0,0,300,50);
        header.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        header.setBackground(Color.gray);

        JPanel body = new JPanel();
        body.setBounds(0,50,300,300);
        body.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        body.setBackground(Color.black);


        add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //setLayout(null);
        setVisible(true);


    }
}
```

Comment: The line `setLayout(null);` won't help.

Comment: Yes thanks, but after removing it, I only see the "body" panel, not the header anymore...

Comment: Using `BorderLayout` (which is default for `JFrame`) would mostly do this.  You could also use `GridBagLayout` which might give you more control.  The problem is, at the end of the day, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion.  If you "need" to restrict a components size, then you need to override `getMinimum/Maximum/PreferredSize`

Comment: *"Yes thanks, but after removing it, I only see the "body" panel, not the header anymore"* - This is because the header panel's default size is `0x0`

Comment: Then don't call setBounds() on `body`; just call setPreferredSize().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `setLayout(null)`, this reverses the work of the earlier `setLayout(new BorderLayout())`

You then need to set the preferred size of both the header and body using `setPreferredSize` instead of using `setBounds()`

```
public Test() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 400);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel header = new JPanel();
    header.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 50));
    header.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    header.setBackground(Color.gray);

    JPanel body = new JPanel();
    body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
    body.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    body.setBackground(Color.black);

    add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer !

Comment: I'd be wary of using `-1` as a sizing this way - there is no documented action about what will happen if you do and it's effect may differ between platforms/versions.  In fact, reading through the code for `BorderLayout`, it simply will add the value to it's calculations when determine the size of it's overall layout and the individual components, meaning that it will try and make the components `-1` pixels wide.  When I tested the code (using `pack` instead of `setSize`), it generates a window which is the minimum width the system allowed window

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer is, you need to take advantage of the layout management framework.

Layout managers work by taking into consideration the preferred/minimum/maximum size of a component - beware though, these are guides only and layout managers may ignore some or all of them based on their needs and the available space.

This is a simple example which overrides the `getPreferredSize` method of the `header` to return a "desirable" size:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

JPanel header = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 50);
    }

};
header.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
header.setBackground(Color.gray);

// I would allow the content of the panel determine the actual size
// but I've overridden `getPreferredSize` for demonstration purposes
JPanel body = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(200, 200);
    }
};
body.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
body.setBackground(Color.black);

frame.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
frame.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
// pack is preferred over setSize, as it will "pack" the window around
// the content, which will produce a more consistent result
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

The problem with doing this is, the component will no longer take into consideration the sizing requirements of its children, so you might end up with some strange side effects.

There are other solutions which might provide some other advantages and disadvantages and you'd need to consider them for your use case.

> Why override `getPreferredSize` rather then calling `setPreferredSize`?

Mostly, control.  You can prevent other parts of the code from modifying the state and you control "how" the calculation gets done.  Sure, nothing stops other codes from extending the component and overriding the method as well, but that's more complicated and doesn't take into consideration scenarios where an instance of the component is provided, rather than created.

> Why use `pack` over `setSize`?

`pack` will "pack" the window frame around the content, so the content will always match its preferred size, rather than shrinking the content so that the frame decorations can be accommodated.  It will, overall, generate a more consistent result across multiple platforms